# change slides div width to image width

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:980px;height:380px;overflow:hidden; ">

        <div data-p="170.00" >
            <img data-u="image" src="../../../Admin/Products and Services/images/<?php echo $img1 ;?>" />
        </div>
<div>
```

In this Jssor slider how can I change sliders div max width to image width. Link to the jssor slider is given below[Jssor Slider](https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.slider). Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you might have more sliders on the page and more images in each slider, this is the way to go:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-u=slides]").forEach(slider=>{
    var maxWidth=0;
    slider.querySelectorAll("img")
        .forEach( image => {
            maxWidth=Math.max(maxWidth,image.width)
        });
    slider.style.maxWidth=maxWidth+"px";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick demo how you can do it:

```
var imageFrame = document.querySelector("div[data-u='slides']");
var imagediv= imageFrame.querySelector("div[data-p='170.00'] > img");

console.log("before: " + imageFrame.offsetWidth, imagediv.offsetWidth);

imageFrame.style.width = imagediv.offsetWidth+"px";

console.log("after: " + imageFrame.offsetWidth, imagediv.offsetWidth);
```

I assumed you wanna stretch the outer div holding the inner div to the size of the inner image of inner div. I also assumed no libs, vanilla only. I also assumed you want it compatible with older browsers so no fancy stuff like arrows.

*If you got multiple photos you are gonna need to add their sizes up with possible margins, borders and paddings in between. That one would require me to see your entire HTML with CSS that styles it so I know what I need to take into account*.

Here is a demo with photo off the internet:

[fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/ecnoybzd/)

Ofc, remove the console logs, they are there in for demo only.